# Can not install node module in GitHub action - npm ERR! error: remote origin already exists

Tags: node.js, npm

I tried to create a GitHub action to build my application and it fails to install node module and return error that `origin already exist`

***Please note that is is not a git fatal error that we get when push/pull***

Please find my GitHub action code

```
name: My Desktop Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - desktop-build

jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: macos-10.15

    steps:
      - name: Check out Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          path: current-repo

      - name: Check out 2nd repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: 5sfayas/private-repo
          path: private-repo
          ref: 'desktop-build'
          ssh-key: ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}

      - name: Adding SSH KEY
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.4
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

      - name: Install npm in private-repo - 2nd repo
        run: |
            cd private-repo
            npm i && npm run build
```

Error

```
npm ERR! code 3
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/5sfayas/node-deperend-private-repo.git
npm ERR! error: remote origin already exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-02-03T04_45_01_401Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My package.json is not updated with the latest changes. which is related to Angular update. I checkout to I pull the mast branch and with my branch and work.